# Run python test inside docker and get the exit code outside on host machine

Tags: python, docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose, teamcity

I have this docker compose file

```
version: "2"
services:
    abc_python_test:
        build: "python"
        container_name: "abc-python-test"
        volumes:
            - "../:/abc/"
        working_dir: "/abc"
        command: "sh -c 'python3 -m unittest tests/calculator.py'"
```

I have a following Makefile

```
test:
    cp config/config-$(env).cfg config/config.cfg
    docker-compose -f environment/test.yml up --build
```

I run this `Makefile` in one of a build step we have in our CI.

Problem is, the test run and fails, the `python3` process get the `exit code 1`. However, once the `python3` process get finished the container gets down. But my host machine shows the `status code 0`. This leads to get my build pass even the tests are failing.

How can I forward this `python3` exit code to my main process so that it knows that the tests got failed.

Thanks

PS: We have old docker compose version that doesn't come with the `--exit-code-from` flag

Comment: so how about updating *docker compose* then?

Comment: That is somehow not in my control.

Answer (score 2):

Run the container in the background:

```
docker run -dit abc-python-test somecommand
```

You can then use

```
docker wait abc-python-test
```

This can get the container's return code if you are sure the container always exit after run, no matter test pass or failure.

Detail refers to [offical guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/wait/).

Comment: If one has tests inside the container then it's possible to run tests on the same docker image by replacing the entry point, e.g. `docker run --entrypoint "pytest" image_name`